# use an input in class on angular2 with typescript

Tags: typescript, angular

I am trying to use an **input** that i sent by *appcomponent* to my select component.

I need to use the value in my class. The problem that it hasn't been identified on my class but when i put it in the template i can see it.

For example in this component:

```
import {Component, Input} from 'angular2/core';
@Component({
selector: 'test',
template: "<h4>test 1 {{test_input}}</h4>   <br>" 
})
export class TestComponent {
private test_test;

@Input() test_input: string;
}
```

I need to use test_input for example to modify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i need to use test_input for example to modify it

If you need to modify the value whenever a value change is propagated to the TestComponent, use a setter:

```
@Input() set test_input(newValue: string) { ... }
```

This is discussed in the Component Interaction cookbook, the [Intercept input property changes with a setter](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#parent-to-child-setter) example.

Answer (score 2):

The input isn't set before `ngOnInit()` is called. Move your code to this method

```
export class TestComponent {
  private test_test;

  @Input() test_input: string;

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.test_input);
  }
}
```

and it will do what you expect.

Comment: it's good but the problem that i need to change it everytime the typeahead change and the onInit works only on initialising the component so i need to find a solution to detect the change on the other component and reload the second component

Comment: You can either use a setter as demonstrated by @MarkRajcok or the `ngOnChanges()` lifecycle method demonstrated by @micronyks.

Comment: i wasn't so clear i will put the code maybe it will explain what isaid

Comment: In that case you might want to add an `@Output() someEvent`, then you can subscribe to `someEvent` events like `<test (someEvent)="doSomething()">`. Not sure though if this is what you want.

Comment: i added an answer i hope i explain better the problem

Comment: `this.items = this.dslam;` in the constructor doesn't do anything. `this.dslam` is not yet set when the constructor is executed. You need to move it to `ngOnChanges` or create a setter like explained by @MarkRajcok

Answer (score 1):

You can even check ***current*** and ***previous*** value of `test_test`variable.

```
export class TestComponent {

  @Input() test_test:string;

  ngOnChanges(...args: any[]) {
        console.log('onChange fired');
        console.log(args[0].test_test.currentValue);
        console.log(args[0].test_test.previousValue)
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.test_input);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this is my ngselect component

```
@Component({
selector: 'select-test',
template: `<ng-select [allow-clear]="true"
            [items]="items"
            [disabled]="disabled"
            (data)="refreshValue($event)"
            (selected)="selected($event)"
            (removed)="removed($event)"
            (typed)="typed($event)"
            [placeholder]="'No city selected'"></ng-select> {{dslam}}`,
directives: [Select, NgClass, CORE_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES, ButtonCheckbox]
})
export class SelectComponent {
private value: any = {};
//private items:Array<string> = [];
@Output() selected_value = new EventEmitter();
@Input() dslam: any;
private _disabledV:string = '0';
private disabled:boolean = false;
private items: Array<string> = [];
constructor(){
  this.items = this.dslam;
}
```

so what i need is to put my input "dslam" which is an array into "items" everytime i change it with my typeahead (which i have the input dslam) the problem that when i change it i can see that it changes but i didn't find the solution to change my array on my select i hope i was clear

Comment: Please don't write follow-ups as answer. Please edit your question and add this to your question and delete this answer.